# EF core get additional table entries as one json column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table named Blog that defined in SQL:

```
create table Blog
(
  SurrogateKey uniqueidentifier not null primary key,
  Text nvarchar(max)
)
```

and a second table named Comments:

```
create table Comments
(
  SurrogateKey uniqueidentifier not null primary key,
  Comment nvarchar(max)
)
```

in EF I have the entities Blog and Comment in C# like:

```
internal class Blog
{
   public Guid SurrogateKey {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Comment> {get;set;}
   // what I want as json or xml
   // public string Comments {get;set;}
}

internal class Comment
{
  public Guid SurrogateKey {get;set;}
  public string Comment {get;set;}
}
```

and the a context like:

```
internal class BlogContext : DBContext
{
  ....

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasKey(blog => blog.SurrogateKey);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().ToTable("Blog");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasKey(comment=> comment.SurrogateKey);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().ToTable("Comment");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(item => item.Comments)
             .WithOne().HasForeignKey(comment => comment.SurrogateKey);
  }
}
```

EF creates then a join like this:

```
select SurrogateKey, Text, Comment from Blog
join Comments on Blog.SurrogateKey = Comments.SurrogateKey
```

then I get all results duplicated on the amount of comments. For performance I want the comments as a string. And It should possible to query for comments. So that I get one Result with the blog and all comments. In SQL I would write:

```
select SurrogateKey, Text, 
Comment = (select Comment 
           from comments where surrogateKey = blog.SurrogateKey 
           AND Comment like '%test%' FOR XML)
from Blog
```

Is it possible to do the same with Enity Framework (3) core? So that I can get the comments for a blog converted as a string? 
And the convert should be done on server side not a query where I later convert the comments object to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) to register a SQL View in your model.

Comment: I am not sure that it solves everthing. With your answer I see I have not explicit say that I also want to filter for comments. I add this to the question. Fits the keyless enity for this? Currently I have not get it run. How can I pass the SurogateKey that I get the comments that fit to the blog?